# datepicker min range between dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, range

I'm using jquery datepicker and I have 2 dates: arrival date and departure date. I want to make that min range between those two dates would be 30 days.

I try to add this, but it doesnt work:

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            if(this.id == 'arr_date'){
              var dateMin = $('#arr_date').datepicker("getDate");
              var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 30);  
              $('#dep_date').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);                  
            }

        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5BbGS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#arr_date").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays,
     onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
         var dParts = selectedDate.split('-');
         var add30Days = new Date(dParts[2] + '/' +
                        dParts[1] + '/' +
                        (+dParts[0] + 30)
               );

       $( "#dep_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", add30Days );
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5BbGS/500/